# How do I get the good ending?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

How do I get the good ending in Five Nights at Freddys 3? I keep on getting the bad ending no matter what the outcome of the minigames are.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen you have to stand around for a while and step inside the 3 things at the top. Also you have to stand on the springtrap/salvage suit itself. That is only a theory from what I have seen in others videos.

Answer (score 1):

A Youtuber did a very detailed explanation of how to get the Good ending and all the minigames. I haven't tried this myself (I don't own the game) but it seems to explain how to get it.

Was posted on Kotaku with the title 'How to get the good ending", so I guess it works.

http://kotaku.com/how-to-get-the-good-ending-in-five-nights-at-freddys-3-1689420840

Comment: Whilst the link and video may answer the question, it'd be better if you could summarize the steps here, to prevent your answer becoming useless should the video/article be removed